# setup facebook login with play + securesocial on localhost error 191

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, playframework, localhost, securesocial

I want to test my play/scala application which uses securesocial locally. It's running on localhost:9000/ on my windows machine. 
When I click on facebook login, it will produce the following URL: 
[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fauth%2Fauthenticate%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&state=188fda6d-5660-4504-9493-4d9034dcd221](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fauth%2Fauthenticate%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&state=188fda6d-5660-4504-9493-4d9034dcd221)

and will give the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Cannot load URL [...]",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "{trace_code}"
   }
}
```

My facebook app is setup as follows:

```
App Domain: localhost
URL of website: http://localhost:9000/
```

I looked already for solutions here and on google, but none of them is working.
E.g. it was not working to modify hosts file to have another domain pointing to localhost.

Am I missing something? Or will be the only way to get it running to create some public ip/domain to my computer as with ngrok (http://ankurm.com/using-localhost-for-facebook-app-development/) or apache?

Does facebook really provide now simpler way for local testing? I cannot really believe that.

Comment: That looks like an outdated address for the login dialog. Use the current one instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

Comment: And where from/at what point do you get that error message? What is the exact URL the message refers to?

Comment: Personally, on my Play! projects I got rid of SecureSocial, and did the Javascript way; because of such configuration errors, or migration problems , or because I found that faster to implement.

Comment: changing authorization_url to be "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" in securesocial settings changes already something. No I get a rendered html page with a dialog showing:  URL blocked... its not in the settings. So somehow the same error? And what do you mean with "what is the exact URL the messeage refers to"? Its the one I posted above with a valid client_id

Comment: Julien D good point, but in the end I need server-to-server-oauth. If I get it right, this won't be possible with javascript?!